# Difference between Const usage in functions in c++

Tags: c++

I'm having the below method with multiple const keywords. why are they used?

```
const int* MyClass::getvalue(const int input) const
```

if returning a pointer from a method, what are the ways to restrict the user from changing the pointer value and pointer itself?

Comment: see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness

Comment: There are no pointers in your code. Which question is the question you're asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having the below method with multiple const keywords. why are they used?
>
> ```
> const int MyClass::getvalue(const int input) const
> ^
> ```

This makes the return value const. There is no reason to use a return by const value. Some compilers will warn if you use const here. Note that conversely, a reference or a pointer to const object  would be reasonable.

> ```
> const int MyClass::getvalue(const int input) const
>                             ^
> ```

This makes the argument const. Whether a value argument is const or not makes little difference. A minor advantage of const is that you can know from the declaration that the local object won't change throughout the function, which can be helpful if the function is complex.

> ```
> const int MyClass::getvalue(const int input) const
>                                              ^
> ```

This makes a member function const. This allows the member function to be called on const instances of the class, but also prevents the function from modifying non-mutable members of the object.

---

> if returning a pointer from a method, what are the ways to restrict the user from changing the pointer value and pointer itself?

There is no way of restricting the user from changing the value of a pointer object that you've returned to them, and there is never a need to do so.

You can restrict the user from modifying the pointe**d** object by returning a pointer to const.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, having the return type for a value (as opposed to a reference or a pointer) being `const` is rather useless. The caller of the function can still copy the value to a non-constant variable anyway. For a reference or a pointer, it means that the referenced/pointed to object can not be modified. It can still be copied to a non-constant object though.

The argument being `const` means that the function can not change the argument. It is partly informational, partly helps the compiler choose optimizations, and for references or pointers means that whatever is referenced/pointed to can't be modified. For references there's also the semantic that you can pass temporary objects to the function.

The last `const` is for the function itself, and makes it so that the function can only be called on `const` objects. If you have a non-const `MyClass` object, this function can't be called on it. This `const` is part of the function signature, together with the function name and its argument types. That means you can have two overloaded functions with the same name and arguments, one being `const` qualified and one not.

Comment: _"For a reference or a pointer, it means that the referenced/pointed to object can not be modified"_ Not really. If the `T1` is `T2*` then `const T1` is useless for the same reasons as any other `T1` that you just outlined. Only if `T1` is `const T2*` is there a use but that's an entirely different scenario.

Answer (score 2):

The last `const` specifies that `getvalue()` won't change the instance of `MyClass` it is called upon.

`const int input` declares a parameter of type `int` to the function `getvalue()` specified as `const`. Its value cannot be changed inside the function.

In the return type `const` is quite meaningless since the returned value can be assigned to a non-const-qualified `int` without problem.

> what are the ways to restrict the user from changing the pointer value and pointer itself?

Read declarations backwards:

```
int const * const foo; // foo is a constant pointer to a constant int
int       * const bar; // bar is a constant pointer to a          int
int const *       qux; // qux is a          pointer to a constant int
```